# ImportError: cannot import name 'hf_bucket_url' in HuggingFace Transformers

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

So I installed the latest version of transformers on Google Colab

```
!pip install transformers
```

When trying to invoke the conversion file using

```
!python /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf2.py .py --help
```

Or trying to use

```
from transformers.file_utils import hf_bucket_url.                                 // works 
from transformers.convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf2 import *.                      // fails

convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf("gpt2", pytorch_file, config_file, tf_file).
```

I get this error

```
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-dadaf83ecea0> in <module>()
      1 from transformers.file_utils import hf_bucket_url
----> 2 from transformers.convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf2 import *
      3 
      4 convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf("gpt2", pytorch_file, config_file, tf_file)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf2.py in <module>()
     20 import os
     21 
---> 22 from transformers import (
     23     ALBERT_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP,
     24     BERT_PRETRAINED_CONFIG_ARCHIVE_MAP,

ImportError: cannot import name 'hf_bucket_url'
```

What's going on?

Comment: Some issue introduced with 2.11. Please open a [bug report](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues) and as a workaround go back to 2.10.0

Comment: I have just sent a PR .. https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/5531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug. [This PR solves the issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/pull/5531) by importing the function `hf_bucket_url` properly.